# Wrap a package/module/callable to a new one with added attributes

Tags: python, python-3.7, wrapper, python-3.9, callable

I want to allow two different access to a particular functions. I'm not the author of sample.test_foo and I am making use of the @service decorator to work in these two ways.

The method say sample.test_foo is decorated by @service and when directly imported and accessed, it will run certain code and return the result.

Other mode I want is to make the function use a cache to fetch the data. How I'm doing this is, I'm asking the users to set a context variable - cache_mode_modules - and users are expected to add "sample". The decorator checks if the parent module is in the env, then it fetches from cache otherwise calls the method. How I fetch from cache etc are bit complex and isn't related to the question.

I really want to change the second mode of access. I want to create an API which takes in "sample" module and returns me a different callable.

```
import sample
new_sample = magic_wrapper(sample)

sample.test_foo() -> calls the actual func
new_sample.foo()  -> calls the cache
```

The magic_wrapper need to set some module variable, say "_cache_mode=True" which I can use it in my decorator and decide how to access.

Note that even if package is passed to the magic_wrapper, I need the functionality to work.

I tried the below one

```
In [1]: def test(module):
   ...:     SPEC_OS = importlib.util.find_spec(module)
   ...:     a = importlib.util.module_from_spec(SPEC_OS)
   ...:     SPEC_OS.loader.exec_module(a)
   ...:     a._cache_mode = True
   ...:     return a
```

It works for module but not for package. Can someone suggest if it is possible to have the magic_wrapper ?

Comment: does changing the module variable cause changes across the whole package or just across a few functions in the package that you are wanting to use?

Comment: I don't think across functions will be possible. If possible, then that will be great. If not also, I can modify my decorator to lookback till the parent package to see if _cache_mode is True or not

Answer (score 0):

From your comment, I think you are trying to change the behavior of specific functions in the package/module by overriding defaults and not actually make changes to the package/module core functionality.  If that is right, functions are first class objects in Python so they can be passed around just like any other object and thus set as a default argument to another function.

Example:

```
def function_in_module(b, default=False):
    if default:
        return -b
    return b

def magic_wrapper(b, func=function_in_module):
    return func(b, default=True)

print(magic_wrapper(10)) # prints -10
print(function_in_module(10)) # prints 10
```

Same is true with an imported from an imported module.  If the above function_in_module were actually in module, you could make a file magic_wrapper.py:

```
from module import function_in_module

def magic_wrapper(b, func=function_in_module):
    return func(b, default=True)
```

and in main.py:

```
from module import function_in_module
from magic_wrapper import magic_wrapper

print(magic_wrapper(10)) # prints -10
print(function_in_module(10)) # prints 10
```

Comment: Nope. wasn't looking for this. I want a new module copy not this manner.